# ASP .NET MVC Kendo Window close exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Title";
}


@(Html.Kendo().Window()
      .Name("activate-window")
      .Title("Car selection")
      .Content ( @<h5>cars:</h5>+
                       @Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                       .Name("vehicle")
                       .DataTextField("Name")
                       .DataSource(ds =>
                       {
                           ds.Read(r =>
                           {
                               r.Action("GetVehicleList", "Home").Data("getVehicle");
                           }).ServerFiltering(true);

                       })
                       .Filter("contains")
                       .MinLength(3).ToHtmlString() +
                       "<h5>Device:</h5>"+
                       @Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                       .Name("device")
                       .DataTextField("Name")
                       .DataValueField("Id")
                       .AutoBind(false)
                       .DataSource(ds =>
                       {
                           ds.Read(r =>
                           {
                               r.Action("GetDevice", "Home").Data("getDevice");
                           }).ServerFiltering(true);

                       })
                       .Filter("contains")
                       .MinLength(3).ToHtmlString()+
                       "<div>"+
                       @Html.Kendo().Button()
                       .Name("close")
                       .Content("Close")
                       .Events(e=>e.Click("close")).ToHtmlString()+
                       "</div>"
      )
      .Animation(a => a.Open(e => e.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
      .Resizable()
      .Draggable()
      .Modal(true)
      .Visible(false)
      .Width(300)

)


@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
      .Name("mainPanel")
      .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Horizontal)
      .Panes(panes =>
      {
          panes.Add()
              .HtmlAttributes(new {id = "left-side"})
              .Scrollable(true)
              .Collapsible(false)
              .Size("250px")
              .Content(Html.Kendo().Button()
                  .Name("activate")
                  .Content("Show window")
                  .Events(e=>e.Click("activateDevice"))
                  .ToHtmlString()
              );

          panes.Add()
              .HtmlAttributes(new {id = "right-side"})
              .Scrollable(true)
              .Collapsible(false)
              .Content(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                  .Name("tabStrip")
                  .Animation(a => a.Open(e => e.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
                  .Items(item =>
                  {
                      item.Add().Text("Events")
                          .Selected(true)
                          .Content(
                              Html.Kendo().Grid<string>()
                                  .Name("events-grid").ToHtmlString()
                          );
                  }).ToHtmlString()
              );
      })
      )

<script>

    function activateDevice(e) {
        var window = $("#activate-window");
        window.data("kendoWindow").center();
        window.data("kendoWindow").open();
    }
    function getVehicle() {
        return {
            text: $("#vehicle").val()
        };

    }

    function getDevice() {
        return {
            text: $("#device").data("kendoMultiSelect").input.val()
        }
    }

    function close(e) {
        $(this).closest(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow").close();
    }


</script>
```

when window open all work ok. When I press close button in window header window closed and all ok. But when I press my close button I get exception in 
Unhandled exception at line 25, column 6830 in http://localhost:22061/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.all.min.js
0x800a01b6 
Object does not support property or method "call"
What I do wrong?